# .htaccess RewriteRule works only if no file exists with that name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use a htaccess rewrite rule like this:

> IF url = `http://example.com/admin/dashboard`
>   LOAD FILE `http://example.come/admin/dashboard.php`

I have this file structure

```
example.com/
|-- admin/
    |-- .htaccess
    |-- dashboard.php
```

if I write this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test$ dashboard.php
```

and type this address on my browser `http://example.com/admin/test`

I correctly see the content of dashboard.php file

But if I change my .htaccess file to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboard.php
```

and type `http://example.com/admin/dashboard` in by browser I get a Not Found page

why RewriteRule works only if my url point to a non-existing file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off `MultiViews` option in your .htaccess which might have been turned on in your server config.

```
Options -MultiViews    
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ dashboard.php [L,NC]
```

You may also add `RewriteBase` just below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteBase /admin/
```

Comment: There was a MultiViews option in my virtual host configuration, thanks!